# Scope of temporary variables -- does Eclipse/compiler optimize?

Tags: java, android, scope

First of all, I ask those with "premature optimization" phobia to spare me: I don't want to optimize anything, I'm just *curious*.

I read/observed two things, including on stackoverflow (can't find the link now):

- For method calls, memory for *all* local variables is reserved "at the beginning" of the method, i.e. even for the variables that are declared in lower-level scopes (I know this is poor wording scientifically, e.g. ignoring how calling mechanism works etc., but I hope the point is clear). Obviously, scopes don't exist for the running program, they are only on source code level for better readability, maintaibility, code structuring, telling the compiler about our intentions (e.g. giving optimization hints, see below).
- One of advantages of declaring variables in the smallest possible scope (i.e. the highest level where they're *still* needed) is that the "compiler **can reuse the memory** for other temporary variables (in other blocks)". This sounds clear & logical to me.

I'm wondering what the compiler/JIT/whatever can actually optimize, and what it can't.

Here is the following method (assume that the variables are actually *used*, so they can't be optimized away for that reason):

```
// The method does many (useful) things, but these were cut here
public void myMethod() {
    int var1 = 1;
    ... // do work
    if (something) {
        int var2 = 2;
        int var3 = 3;
        ... // do work
    }
    int var4 = 4;
    int var5 = 5;
    ... // do work
}
```

1.) Is the compiler able to detect that the space for `var2` and `var3` can be reused for `var4` and `var5`? I don't remember seeing such a thing in disassembled bytecodes.

2.) Is the code method above equivalent to the case when the end of the method is put to {} too?

```
public void myMethod() {
    int var1 = 1;
    ... // do work
    if (something) {
        int var2 = 2;
        int var3 = 3;
        ... // do work
    }
    {
        int var4 = 4;
        int var5 = 5;
        ... // do work
    }
}
```

Finally, let's see a simpler case:

```
public void myMethod() {
    int var1 = 1;
    ... // do work, and then don't refer to var1 any more

    int var4 = 4;
    int var5 = 5;
    ... // do work      
}
```

3.) In this case, can `var1` memory be reused for `var4` (or `var5`)? I.e. in such a case, it is enough for the method to have memory for **two** local `int` variables, not for three.

(I know that in theory, these are obvious cases for the compiler, but sometimes I overlook things e.g. why a compiler *can't* do or assume anything.)

Comment: Example 2 has invalid code, did you mean to put an `else`?

Comment: @Raeki: it's valid code, Java allows that. You can declare such blocks, and then the variables in them won't be accessible from upper blocks (i.e., in this case, from the method body itself).

Comment: My bad - learned something (`else` (ha)) new today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. The stack slot can be reused after the nested }, and I have seen javac do so.
2. Yes. Cases 1 and 2 are equivalent. The second nested {} changes nothing, unless something follows it.
3. The Java compiler won't optimize this, although in theory given all the right conditions it conceivably could. If the variables are final it is possible not to assign a slot for them at all.

Another thing you should note is that there is no byte code instruction corresponding to the nested }, so the JVM and therefore HotSpot has no basis for knowing where a nested scope ends and therefore where a stack slot changes usage.

Answer (score 3):

I can speak for compilers for real CPUs, I'm not sure about JVM compiler and I don't think that at compile level code is optimized as much as you think (the Java platform simply don't care too much about memory foorprint as you can imagine).

For real compilers these scenarios are actually optimized very often. This is done not at high level language level but at a lower intermediate level like at [RTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_transfer_language) level. Everything is made with the purpose of register allocation or stack allocation and works by computing living sets for variables inside functions.

This means that when the code is compiled everything is translated to RTL by assuming an arbitrary number of temporary registers and then for each temporary, its live state is calculated through the so-called [live variable analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liveness_analysis). This is just one of the ways to optimize such things.

Eg

- var1 live scope is from instruction 1 to 10
- var2 live scope is from instruction 5 to 17
- var3 live scope is from instruction 3 to 25
- and so on

This is done after having splitted the code into blocks which does not contain jumps or labels so that you are sure about the flow inside any specified block.

After this computation you can easily see which variables are needed for most time, which become useless and can free their reserved space and so on. This is done so that you are able to fit as much variables as possible into registers and optimize the assembled code a lot.

Personally I don't think the **javac** does any of this (even because the JVM is stack based so this would just break memory allocation on objects without any need nowadays), but my is just speculation.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful information. I upvoted it. Since EJP's answer focuses more on the Java aspects of the original question, I've set that as the answer.